# GCC compliler causing error of illegal refference for access noxim

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++

I am trying to run access noxim (network simulation too) on my Ubuntu 14 and concerning this source.

```
https://github.com/habedi/SystemC-AccessNoxim
```

I am using systemc2.3.1 for this purpose. Now i have gcc 4.8.4 on my system. When i make my access noxim it generates errors.

```
    enter code hereNoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5ce): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x8cb): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x8df): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x8e6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x8f7): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x922): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x92a): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x936): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xa5a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xa7a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xa8e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xa95): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xaa6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xad1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xad9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xae5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc0a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc2a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc3e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc45): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc56): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc81): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc89): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xc95): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xdba): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xdda): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xdee): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xdf5): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xe06): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xe31): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xe39): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xe45): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xf6a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xf8a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xf9e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xfa5): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xfb6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xfe1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xfe9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xff5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x111a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x113a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x114e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1155): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1166): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1191): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1199): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x11a5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x12ca): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x12ea): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x12fe): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1305): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1316): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1341): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1349): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1355): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x147a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x149a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x14ae): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x14b5): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x14c6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x14f1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x14f9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1505): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x162a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x164a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x165e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1665): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1676): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x16a1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x16a9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x16b5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x17da): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x17fa): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x180e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1815): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1826): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1851): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1859): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1865): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x198a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x19aa): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x19be): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x19c5): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x19d6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1a01): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1a09): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1a15): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1b3a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1b5a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1b6e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1b75): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1b86): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1bb1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1bb9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x1bc5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x516a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x518a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x519e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x51a5): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x51b6): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x51e1): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x51e9): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x51f5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x531a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x533a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x534e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5355): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5366): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5391): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5399): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x53a5): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x54ca): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x54ea): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x54fe): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5505): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5516): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5541): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5549): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5555): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5750): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5770): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5784): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x578b): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x579c): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x57c7): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x57cf): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x57db): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x58fe): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x591e): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5932): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5939): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x594a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5975): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x597d): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x5989): undefined reference to `vtable for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x9253): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x9265): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x9272): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x92da): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x92ec): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p'
./NoximMain.o:NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0x92f9): more undefined references to `sc_core::sc_process_b::m_delete_next_p' follow
./NoximMain.o: In function `NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)':
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xca9a): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xcaaa): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xcac1): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xcad8): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xcadf): undefined reference to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>'
./NoximMain.o:NoximMain.cpp:(.text._ZN8NoximNoCC1EN7sc_core14sc_module_nameE[NoximNoC::NoximNoC(sc_core::sc_module_name)]+0xcbbd): more undefined references to `VTT for sc_core::sc_signal<bool>' follow
./thermal_IF.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
thermal_IF.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_api_version_2_2_0::sc_api_version_2_2_0()'
./NoximVLink.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
NoximVLink.cpp:(.text+0xbd): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_api_version_2_2_0::sc_api_version_2_2_0()'
./NoximLog.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
NoximLog.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `sc_core::sc_api_version_2_2_0::sc_api_version_2_2_0()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now the Makefile of mine is

```
    TARGET_ARCH = linux64
CC     = g++
OPT    = -O3
DEBUG  = -g
OTHER  = # -Wall -Wno-deprecated
CFLAGS = $(OPT)

VPATH = ../src:.
MODULE = noxim
SRCS = ./NoximNoC.cpp ./NoximRouter.cpp ./NoximProcessingElement.cpp ./NoximBuffer.cpp \
    ./NoximStats.cpp ./NoximGlobalStats.cpp ./NoximGlobalRoutingTable.cpp \
    ./NoximLocalRoutingTable.cpp ./NoximGlobalTrafficTable.cpp ./NoximReservationTable.cpp \
    ./NoximPower.cpp ./NoximCmdLineParser.cpp ./NoximMain.cpp ./thermal_IF.cpp ./NoximVLink.cpp \
        ./NoximLog.cpp 
SRCS_C = ./util.c ./temperature_grid.c ./temperature_block.c ./temperature.c \
        ./shape.c ./RCutil.c ./npe.c ./package.c ./flp.c
OBJS_C = $(SRCS_C:.c=.o )
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJS_A = $(OBJS) 
OBJS_A += $(OBJS_C)
include ./Makefile.defs
```

MakeFile.defs is

```
#############################
# Noxim - the NoC Simulator #
#############################

# NOTE FOR NOXIM USERS: before running "make" you just have to modify
# the following variable to point to your SystemC installation path
#
SYSTEMC = /usr/local/systemc211
#
# That's all for you!!!

INCDIR = -I. -I.. -I../src -I$(SYSTEMC)/include
LIBDIR = -L. -L.. -L../src -L$(SYSTEMC)/lib-$(TARGET_ARCH)

#EXTRA_LIBS = -lpthread
LIBS = -lsystemc -lm $(EXTRA_LIBS)

EXE    = $(MODULE)

.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c .o 

$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(OBJS_C) $(SYSTEMC)/lib-$(TARGET_ARCH)/libsystemc.a 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) -o $@ $(OBJS_A) $(LIBS) 2>&1 | c++filt

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) -c $<

.c.o:
    gcc -c $(INCDIR) $<
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) *~ *.o $(EXE) core

depend: 
    makedepend $(SRCS) -Y -f Makefile.deps

include ./Makefile.deps
```

Now kindly tell me how to tackle this error. Is problem is from compiler side or systemc2.3.1 or the acces noxim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors like these:

> `./thermal_IF.o: In function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)': thermal_IF.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to sc_core::sc_api_version_2_2_0::sc_api_version_2_2_0()`

usually indicate that the library you're linking against does not provide the API that the application expects.  You said you have systemc2.3.1, can you re-try with systemc2.2.0?

Comment: I tried a lot to install systemc2.2.1 but when i try to configure                 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1                             error comes again and again because i have gcc 4.8 with multiple threads causing trouble for older version of systemc. Help me in this case. Thanks